# How can I send many types of values using AJAX POST method?

Tags: php, ajax

How can I send many types of data with AJAX?

I don't know how to write `data` in this function for this state:

```
$('#edit_product').live('click', function () {
    var category = $('#category').val();
    var pro_name = "My name";

    var id = [];
    $(".value").each(function() {
        value.push($(this).val());
    });

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/add.product.php',

        data: ,  // What do I have to put here???
        success: function (data) {
            $('#result').html(data);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Adding something similar you will get post request with fields "category", "pro_name" and "id"

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/add.product.php',
        data: {
            category: category,
            pro_name: pro_name,
            id: id
        },
        success: function (data) {
            $('#result').html(data);
        }
    });
```